# Laravel 5: allow user to edit post if he's the owner of the post or the owner of the forum category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So far I was able to allow the user to edit his own posts but whenever I through the `if he's owner of the subreddit/category` condition, it stops working altogether.

I have these 3 table

```
Users: id, name, email...
Subreddits: id, name, user_id...
Posts: id, link, title, user_id, subreddit_id...
```

This is the `edit()` method in `PostsController.php`

```
public function edit(Post $post, Subreddit $subreddit)
    {
        if(Auth::id() !== $post->user_id) {
            return view('home')->withErrors('You cannot do that');
        } else {
            return view('post/edit')->with('post', $post)->with('subreddit', $subreddit);
        }
    }
```

And this is the view

```
@if(Auth::id() == $post->user_id)
      <a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', [$post->id]) }}">Edit</a>
@endif
```

This works fine, it only checks if the logged in user_id is the same as the posts's user_id and updating goes through.

But if I added `if(Auth::id() == $subreddit->user_id)` it stops working. It displays the "Edit" link on the view on all the posts but clicking on any of them gives me the validation error `You cannot do that` even for posts that I own.

So how can I check if the users is the owner of the article OR the owner of the category to display and allow EDIT?

Updated method with `$subreddit->user_id`

```
public function edit(Post $post, Subreddit $subreddit)
    {
        if(Auth::id() == $post->user_id || Auth::id() == $subreddit->user_id) {
            return view('post/edit')->with('post', $post)->with('subreddit', $subreddit);
        } else {
            return view('home')->withErrors('You cannot do that');
        }
    }
```

View

```
@if(Auth::id() == $post->user_id || Auth::id() == $subreddit->user_id)
      <a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', [$post->id]) }}">Edit</a>
@endif
```

This will allow me to edit my own posts but will still give me the validation error `You cannot do that` on posts in my own forum category/subreddit.

This is the `Gate` policies that I've tried but it also didn't work

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // Authorizations and Permissions
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        parent::registerPolicies($gate);

        $gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
                return $user->id === $post->user_id;
        });

        $gate->define('mod-update-post', function ($user, $subreddit) {
            return $user->id === $subreddit->user_id;
        });
    }
```

PostsController.php

```
public function edit(Post $post, Subreddit $subreddit, User $user)
    {
        if(Gate::denies('update-post', $post) && Gate::denies('mod-update-post', $subreddit)) {
        return view('home')->withErrors('You cannot do that');
    } else {
        return view('post/edit')->with('post', $post)->with('subreddit', $subreddit);
    }
    }
```

View

```
@can('update-post', $post)
     <a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', [$post->id]) }}">Edit</a>
@endcan
```

With the above code, I am finally able to edit posts if 'update-post' is true but I cannot check if `mod-update-post` is also true, I keep receiving the validation error `You cannot do this`

`dd($subreddit)` inside edit() method shows an empty array. https://cryptbin.com/x6V6wX#26810f755a62f6c8837c0c0fe0371dcf

EDIT: I think I've solved it. I used `$post->subreddit->user->id` instead of `$subreddit->user_id` because that was returning null. And now it all seems to work based on if posts belongs to user or user is forum owner.

But the edit link on the view still shows whether or not I have access. I am unable to double check for `update-post` and `mod-update-post` simultaneously. and using `@can('update-post', $post)` only works once, I cannot double check that.

Comment: Look into policies: http://laraveldaily.com/laravel-5-1-11-introduces-acl-system/

Comment: "But if I added if(Auth::id() == $subreddit->user_id)" : I don't get where you add this. Please show a modified code snippet.

Comment: I tried the `Gate` facade but I couldn't check for two `@can` on the view so I reverted back to the default way of checking it. I had the exact gate policy that checks if `$user->id === $post->user_id` but when I added a second gate that checks if `$user->id === $subreddit->user_id` it stopped working and started behaving as I described in my original post.

Comment: @bernie I updated my post.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Try dumping the contents (print_r, etc.) of `$subreddit` as I suspect it might not contain what you expect. Also, make sure you also secure the POST route of your editing process, not just the form display view.

Comment: @bernie I am already using a middleware for create and edit methods. I just `dd($subreddit);` at the top of the edit() method and you're right, it contains nothing. http://cryptb.in/x6V6wX#26810f755a62f6c8837c0c0fe0371dcf

Comment: @bernie I think I've solved it. I used `$post->subreddit->user->id` instead of `$subreddit->id` because that was returning null. It all works now but I am still unable to check for both `update-post` and `mod-update-post` on the view. Cannot check `@if can || can`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So how can I check if the users is the owner of the article OR the owner of the category to display and allow EDIT?

Use Laravel’s new [authorization component](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization).

**EDIT:** I think you’re misunderstanding how authorization should be used. It should be used to check if the *current user* can perform an action (or not). Therefore, you don’t want to be defining multiple methods for different users types.

Take editing a post for example. There’s the name of your authorization check: `@can('edit', $post)`. You don’t need to define a different one for regular users, and another for moderators. Just add the logic to your edit post method:

```
class PostPolicy
{
    public function edit(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        // If user is administrator, then can edit any post
        if ($user->isModerator()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is the post author
        if ($user->id === $post->author_id) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I’m doing the different checks in the same method, so in your Blade template you can just do this:

```
@can('edit', $post)
    <a href="{{ route('post.edit', $post->getRouteKey()) }}">Edit post</a>
@endcan
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: I tried that before, I added a new policy `mod-update-post` that would `return $user->id === $subreddit->user_id;` but I couldn't check for two `@can` on the view and I found no documentation on the subject.

Comment: That’s because you’re supposed to define a role for what you’re checking for, instead of combining them, i.e. `@can('edit', $post)`. Just do two boolean checks in that method on your policy instead of trying to combine checks in your view (which you shouldn’t be).

Comment: I have edited my post and added my gate policies, but it is still not working properly. I can see the EDIT link now on my posts but cannot edit them, getting the validation error.

Comment: I refined my code, Gate policy `update-post` is working, but `mod-update-post` is not. And I still need to use `@can` on the view otherwise everyone would be able to see the EDIT link.

Comment: Yes. So use `@can('edit', $post)` and then add your logic that determines whether the user can edit the post or not, and show the link if so.

Comment: Well I solved it by using the Gate facade within the if statement. Works like a charm. and I switched back to the Gate policies, better.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to give you an example of how you should be doing authorization checks.

Comment: Thank you for that. But I am still confused about `isModerator` where is that coming from? in PhpStorm, I'm getting `Method not found in App\User` - do I need to create that?

Comment: Yes. It’s example code for demonstration purposes; not to be copy-and-pasted. I don’t know how you designate how users are moderators; that’s up to you to implement.

Comment: I use the same policy as you mentioned. However, how do you handle if I copied the edit URL of the post and logout then login to a different user and paste it, still allowing me to edit the post (even though I am not the rightful owner to edit).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative technique (maybe a little bit simpler) is described here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dont-allow-user-to-change-others-posts

So the idea is to implement a subclass of Request, where you can implement validation rules, and where you can also implement an 'authorize' method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make new folder in App\Http as Rules:

And add a new Rule  file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\Post;

class IsOwner implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return auth()->user()->id == Post::find($value)->user_id;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'You are forbidden from taking this action!';
    }
}
```

Then I just import this class and use as a validation rule: `'post' => ['required', new IsOwner()]`